# Eventmachine HTTP - How to get notified if connection is lost?

Tags: eventmachine

I have this EM http code:

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http'
require 'json'

http = EM::HttpRequest.new("api_url", :keepalive => true, :connect_timeout => 0, :inactivity_timeout => 0)

EventMachine.run do

  s = http.get({'accept' => 'application/json'})
  s.stream do |data|
    puts data
  end

  s.errback do
    puts "FATAL EM STOPPED: #{response.error}"
    EM.stop
  end

end
```

I want to get notified if the connection is lost. I just tried to disable my WIFI and nothing is triggered. After I enable my WIFI the connection is established again and the messages are printed again. I want this behavior I just want to catch that the connection is lost, so that I can raise a error message.

Comment: Your code example references a `response` variable, but you haven't initialised it?

Comment: Just updated the code.